# Django Postgres import error: is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sockets

I am running on a shared bluehost box. The weird thing is that my site runs fine online. I can pull up the django /admin/ site just fine. However, I can't run `manage.py migrate` or make any queries to the database through the `manage.py shell`. Here is the error I am getting:

```
File "/home2/univetg1/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home2/univetg1/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

here are my database settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'univetg1_lunchbox',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

It's weird because I haven't been playing around with my settings.py file or anything and things have been working fine until just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably limited by the number of connections you can make to DB, either increase this in conf or kill some existing connections.

My other guess is that you are not using same type of django settings as you do with your production processes. So you should check what settings file are you using (its specified or in ENV).

Comment: How would I kill the DB connections?

Comment: I shut down my ssh window and re opened it. That seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you *read the error message* before saying that? It's not like PostgreSQL says "ERROR: I dunno what happened, make some random guesses".

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error like:

```
ERROR: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

then the server is:

- not running;
- running on a port other than 5432; or
- configured with a different `unix_socket_directories` path so it's not listening for the socket in `/tmp`

We know that the server is running since your Django site is working. So it's presumably a matter of connection info. Assuming that Django is actually using the data in `settings.py`, it must be on port 5432 as well.

So my guess is that it's using a different `unix_socket_directories`. Maybe the `libpq` you're linking to at runtime on an interactive console is different to the one being linked to when running the service.

You could try connecting over TCP/IP by specifying the host as `localhost`. Otherwise, check what `unix_socket_directories` is set to in `postgresql.conf` and set that as your `HOST`.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue to this but different solution.

My Gunicorn server running Django's wsgi worked fine and could reach the remote database. When I tried to run anything with `python3 manage.py ...`, I would get the error asking if the database was running locally. I could not figure out why `python3 manage.py` was trying to connect to a local Postgres instance but Gunicorn was able to access the remote database fine.

The problem:

I was sourcing a `.prod.env` file that looked like this.

```
DB_NAME=postgres
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
DB_HOST=myhost.com
DB_PORT=5432
```

In Gunicorn, these variables were set because I was setting this file as my `EnvironmentFile` in my `gunicorn.service` that systemd was reading.

For `python3 manage.py ...` commands, I was doing `source .prod.env` and then running `python3 manage.py ...` directly from the shell. When you define a variable in the way I was doing above, it's **not** an environment variable. It's a **shell variable**. It isn't available to the processes you spawn from that shell.

To define an environment variable and source it, your environment file should look like this.

```
export DB_NAME=postgres
export DB_USER=myuser
export DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
export DB_HOST=myhost.com
export DB_PORT=5432
```

Now, when I ran `source .prod.env`, these variables were environment variables and available to any processes spawned from that shell.

2 days of bashing my head and print statements in Django's source code for this to be my solution.

Comment: This is good information and would be helpful for someone in your exact situation but it doesn't really seem like an answer to this question, especially given that there are other answers already and it's an ancient question. This answer seems misplaced to me.