# Postgres data base engine value

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hi there is a full full traceback error that told to supply engine value to postgres data base

```
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/dmitry_tok/Desktop/Projects/foodgram-project-react/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Im try to switch my SQlite3 data base to postgres
There is a settings.py:

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.getenv('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT')
    }
}
```

the .env file:

```
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
DB_NAME=postgres 
POSTGRES_USER=postgres 
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
```

I've tried to search more info about how to setup a postgres in to Django
But all these attempts are not help me at all(((
Which configuration's I need to add to solve this problem?

```
django==3.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is Engine value. It must be 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

Comment: I've tried it : "django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?"
Im also try it with port 5432 and 8000, same error

Comment: Have you tried without a specific port?  DB_PORT=“”

Comment: yea, in this case Django automatically put port 5432

Comment: This is a different problem that the original one. Please, check this link and good luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769258/django-postgres-import-error-is-the-server-running-locally-and-accepting-connec/33769792